# Loop over a nested list and add each index of each nested list to another list

Tags: python, list

What I'm trying to do is to put each index 0 of each item of list a in the list x and each index 1 of each item of list a in the list y. When the plot is shown, it only appears one point. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
a = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [5,6], [6,7]]

for item in a:
    x = [ ]
    y = [ ]
    x.append(item[0])
    y.append(item[1])


plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.axis([-50, 50, -50, 50])
plt.show()
```

Comment: In each loop iteration you set x and y to an empty list. Move x = [] and y = [] out of the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the values of `x` and `y` every time through the loop, so only the last point is stored. Move your declaration of `x` and `y` outside of your loop.

It makes more sense to take advantage of Python's list comprehensions though:

```
x, y = ([p for p,q in a], [q for p,q in a])
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.axis([-50, 50, -50, 50])
plt.show()
```

List comprehension:

```
([p for p,q in a], [q for p,q in a])
```

this piece of code returns a 2-tuple whose elements are two Python lists. The lists are formed using a [list comphrehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which takes each list of x,y and splits the xs into the first returned list, and the ys into the second.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! :) Can you explain a little more about list comprehensions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`x, y = zip(*a)`

It is compact and readable and it should work.